# UDP socket demultiplexing at server port

Tags: c, linux, networking, tcp, udp

TCP socket demultiplexing at the server port (which listens for multiple TCP connections) happens with a separate socket descriptor created for each established  TCP connection(though the accept() call) and the socket descriptor is tightly coupled with tuple [**source IP address, source port, destination IP address, destination IP address**]. Over this established connection we can use the high layer application protocols like HTTP, FTP, SSH etc.,

But in case of UDP there is no session/connection established between the peers. The server waiting at the particular port receives the message from any client. The client's IP address and port number is known after receiving the message(populated in the socket address structure). From the address structure the messages can be demultiplexed and given to respective applications.

Over the server port, If I want to establish a connected session over UDP[like the tuple mentioned in case of TCP] so that communication between the server and client (between particular port on server and client) can be demultiplexed before receiving the message(without inferring the same from socket address structure) so that the higher layer protocols can work like on TCP (ofcourse higher layer protocols like DTLS taking care of the reliability)

Below is the code for UDP server(leveraging the connect() API to keep the UDP socket connected) and UDP client

```
// server program for udp connection 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <strings.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PORT 5000 
#define MAXLINE 1000 

//logical thread num
static unsigned int threadnum = 0;

struct pass_info {
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    unsigned int threadnum;
};

char *message = "Hello Client"; 

void* connection_handle(void *info) {
    int fd = 0;
    char buffer[100];
    int n = 0;
    const int on = 1;
    struct pass_info *pinfo = (struct pass_info*) info;

    printf("Executing thread : %d\n", pinfo->threadnum);

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("Error socket!!!");
        return;
    }

    setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const void*) &on, (socklen_t) sizeof(on));

    bind(fd, (const struct sockaddr *) &pinfo->server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &pinfo->client_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    while(1)
    {
        n = recv(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if (n < 0)
        {
            printf("receive failed! in thread : %d", pinfo->threadnum);
            break;
        }

        buffer[n] = '\0'; 
        printf("Thread num %d: Recv message - %s\n", pinfo->threadnum, buffer);

        n = send(fd, message, sizeof(message), 0);
        if (n < 0)
        {
            printf("send failed! in thread : %d", pinfo->threadnum);
            break;
        }
    }

    free(info);

    return NULL;
}

int main() 
{ 
    char buffer[100]; 
    int listenfd, len, sockfd; 
    const int on = 1;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr; 
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 
    struct pass_info *info;
    pthread_t tid;

    // Create a UDP Socket 
    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);       
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 

    setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const void*) &on, (socklen_t) sizeof(on));
    // bind server address to socket descriptor 
    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 

    while (1)
    {
        //receive the datagram 
        len = sizeof(cliaddr); 
        int n = recvfrom(listenfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 
                0, (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr,&len); //receive message from server 
        buffer[n] = '\0'; 
        printf("Main thread: Recv message - %s\n", buffer); 

        n = sendto(listenfd, message, MAXLINE, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr)); 

        info = (struct pass_info*) malloc (sizeof(struct pass_info));
        memcpy(&info->server_addr, &servaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        memcpy(&info->client_addr, &cliaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        threadnum++;

        info->threadnum = threadnum;
        if (pthread_create(&tid, NULL, connection_handle, info) != 0) {
            perror("pthread_create");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

> 

```
// udp client  program 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <strings.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include<netinet/in.h> 
#include<unistd.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 

#define PORT 5000 
#define MAXLINE 1000 

int main() 
{ 
    char buffer[100]; 
    char *message = "Hello Server"; 
    int sockfd, n; 
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr; 
    int len = 0;

    // clear servaddr 
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 

    // create datagram socket 
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); 

    while(1)
    {
        sleep(3);
        sendto(sockfd, message, MAXLINE, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 

        // waiting for response 
        recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr, &len); 
        puts(buffer); 

    }
}
```

**Queries:**

1. Whether this would be the right way to do de-multiplexing at the UDP socket level
2. The server listens for any UDP packets from the client. once it receives a message, new socket descriptor is created and the connect() API is called so that the client's IP address, port is registered with this newly created socket descriptor and from here on newly created socket descriptor will used to send and receive messages to the particular client's IP address and port. Whether it is a fool proof method
3. Are there any other well known methods to use the higher layer protocols(protocols supporting reliability like DTLS) over UDP